# Sum over cyclic permutation of indices

Tags: summation, code-review, permutation

To define the Schouten bracket I need to be able to sum over a cyclic permutation of the indices:
$$ [\Phi,\Xi]_S=\mathfrak S_{i,j,k}  \left(\Phi^{is}\partial_s\Xi^{jk}+ \Xi^{is}\partial_s\Phi^{jk}\right)\,,$$

where $\mathfrak S_{i,j,k} $ denotes the cyclic sum.

I am aware of the related posts however trying it myself I am not sure the implementation is correct:

```
ps = Permute[{i, j, k}, CyclicGroup[3]];

Sch[A_, B_] := Sum[Sum[A[[ps[[r]][[1]],s]]D[B[[ps[[r]][[2]],ps[[r]][[3]]]],X[[s]]]+B[[ps[[r]][[1]],s]] D[A[[ps[[r]][[2]],ps[[r]][[3]]]],X[[s]]],{s,4},{r,3}],{i,4},{j,4},{k,4}]
```

The indices $i,j,k$ range over 1 to 4, and $X$ are my local coordinates.

---

EDIT: Indeed I was to brief, I won't to check that for example the following matrix $\Pi$:

```
{{0, 0, (1 + z1 zb1), z1 zb2}, {0, 0, z2 zb1, (1 - z1 zb1)}, {-(1 + z1 zb1), -z2 zb1, 0, 0}, {-z1 zb2, -(1 - z1 zb1), 0, 0}}
```

defines a Poisson bivector for the 2-dimensional projective space i.e. $[\Pi,\Pi]_S=0$. The local coordinates are $z_1,\bar z_1,z_2,\bar z_2$.

The reference that I am using is M. V. Karasev and V. P. Maslov - Nonlinear Poisson Brackets. Geometry and Quantization, this is the pertinent excerpt

[image: Poisson]

Comment: This is hard to check without any context. Please give examples of the entities `A` and `B` that want to stuff into `Sch`.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand as you have not given examples of expected inputs and outputs. That being said, I suppose you want a sum like `Sum[f @@ idx, {i, 4}, {j, 4}, {k, 4}, {idx, NestList[RotateLeft, {i, j, k}, 2]}]`.

Comment: can you clarify separately your letter meaning by code also!
because it get me confused! so we try to help you

Comment: @Sch, J. M. is slightly pensive and Alrubaie Thank you already taking a look. I added details :-)